# Indexing matrix in numpy using Node id

Tags: numpy, networkx

Is there a way to index a numpy matrix, built via networkx as an adjacenjy matrix, using node name
(I built the networkx graph parsing lines from a .txt file.
 Each line represents an edge and it's in the form `SourceNode:DestNode:EdgeWeight`)
I need the matrix because I'm going to calculate the hitting probabilities of some nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of how you constructed your graph, you can compute an adjacency matrix of it.  The [docs](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html) state that the order of the rows and columns in this graph will be "as produced by `G.nodes()`" if you don't specify it.

For example,

```
# create your graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
with open("spec.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    for src, dest, weight in line.split(':'):
      G.add_edge(src, dest, weight=weight)

# create adjacency matrix
# - store index now, in case graph is changed.
nodelist = G.nodes()
# extract matrix, and convert to dense representation
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G, nodelist=nodelist).todense()

# normalise each row by incoming edges, or whatever
B = A / A.sum(axis=1).astype(float)
```

Let us presume that your nodes are labelled alphabetically, C-G.  The node ordering is just according to the dictionary hash, and this sequence for me: `['C', 'E', 'D', 'G', 'F']`.
If you want to look up information from the matrix, you could use a lookup like this:

```
ix = nodelist.index('D') # ix is 2 here
print A[ix,:]
```

Comment: The method to lookup is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help!!